# TLS 1.3: the key_share in a ClientHello after a HelloRetryRequest

Tags: tls, key-exchange, openssl

In TLS 1.3 [draft-21](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-21), if there is a `ClientHello` with a `key_share`, say, $(G_1, g^x)$, the server can send a `HelloRetryRequest` to request a new `key_share` value, e.g. ($G_2, g^y)$.

My questions are:

1. When the client send the second `ClientHello`, does it replace the old `key_share` with the new one? i.e, does the new `key_share` in the second `ClientHello` becomes $(G_2, g^x)$ or becomes $[(G_1, g^x), (G_2, g^y)]$?
2. When the server ask for a new `key_share` in the `HelloRetryRequest`, does it send its public value with $(G_2, g^y)$ it or just the Group $(G_2)$?
3. What does the `key_share` contain? it is confusing. In some cases I get the impression it is the group and the public-key $(G_1, g^x)$, in others, like in the `HelloRetryRequest`, I get the impression it is only the group $(G_2)$.

Need more clarification on what is supposed to be sent in the `key_share` in both: `ClientHello`, `HelloRetryRequest`, and the second `ClientHello` after the `HelloRetryRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When the client sends a new ClientHello after a HelloRetryRequest, it replaces the old KeyShare with the one the server requested in the HelloRetryRequest. This is according to my interpretation for the following text in the TLS 1.3 draft 21 [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-21#page-40):

> the new ClientHello, the client MUST    replace the original
> "key_share" extension with one containing only a    new KeyShareEntry
> for the group indicated in the selected_group field    of the
> triggering HelloRetryRequest.

If you have any comments to confirm or correct me, please post before I accept my answer.